# Vulnerable Keys? CVE-2008-0166 openssl DSA Key Signature Blacklist coverage?

Tags: openssl, random, key-generation, cve, debian

Would the current set of [DSA key blacklists](https://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys#Scope_of_the_blacklists) detect a DSA key that was generated with openssl on an affected/vulnerable system, BUT whose DSA parameters (`dsaparam`) were generated on an unaffected system?

Additionally, would the current weak key detection tools,e.g., [ssh-vulnkey](https://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys#Testing_keys_using_ssh-vulnkey) or [dowkd.pl](https://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys#Testing_keys_using_dowkd.pl), miss keys generated this way?

I.e.,

On an unaffected system:

```
$ openssl dsaparam -out dsap.pem 1024
```

Copy `dsap.pem` to an affected system.

On an affected system:

```
$ openssl gendsa -out dsakeys.pem dsap.pem
```